# Should I free allocated memory upon fatal error?

Tags: c, memory, free, fatal-error, quit

Sometimes things like library errors will not allow my program to continue further, like a call to `SDL_Init` going bad. Should I attempt to free as much memory as possible, or just quit? I haven't seen any small examples where people don't just quit, but I'm not smart enough to read DOOM-3 code or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't. If your program crashes, because of some exotic, unforeseen things that happen in your program, it might even be pointless to try and free any allocated heap memory.
I think it'd be best if you just call `exit (EXIT_FAILURE)`, if you can, and leave the OS to reclaim the memory you allocated as good as it possibly can.

However, I would try to clean up any *other* resources that you've used/claimed/opened that may also cause leak. Close as many opened file pointers as you can, or flush any buffers lying around.
Other than that, I'd say: leave it to the OS. Your program has crashed, or is crashing: trying to clean up after yourself in an unforeseen situation might be pointless, or -who knows- eventually do more harm than good.

Of course, if by *"a library errors"* you mean something like:

```
MYSQL *connection = mysql_init();
if (connection == NULL)
{//connection could not be initiated
    //what to do here?
}
```

Or, no lib:

```
char **arr_of_strings = malloc(200*sizeof(char *));
//some code
arr_of_strings[0] = calloc(150, sizeof(char));
//some more
arr_of_strings[120] = calloc(350, sizeof(char));
if (arr_of_strings == NULL)
{//ran out of heap memory
    //what do I do here?
}
```

So, basically: it's a matter of: What does your program have to *do*, and can you easily find a way around the problems you're being faced with.
If, for example, you're writing a mysql client, and the `mysql_init` call fails, I think it pretty evident you *cannot* continue. You could try to provide a fallback for every reason why this could happen, or you could just exit. I'd opt for the latter.
In the second case, it's pretty clear that you've depleted the heap memory. If you're going to write these strings to a file anyway, you could prevent this kind of error like so:

```
int main()
{
    char **arr_str = malloc(20*sizeof(char *));
    const char *fileName = "output.txt";
    int i, j;
    int alloc_str(char ***str, int offset, int size);
    void write_to_file(const char *string, const char *fileName);
    for(i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        if (alloc_str(&arr_str, i, 100+i) == -1)
        {
            if (i == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);//this is a bigger problem
            for (j=0;i<i;++j)
            {//write what we have to file, and free the memory
                if (arr_str[j] != NULL)
                {
                    write_to_file(arr_str[j], fileName);
                    free(arr_str[j]);
                    arr_str[j] = NULL;
                }
                if (alloc_str(&arr_str, i, 100+i) != -1) break;//enough memory freed!
            }
        }
        //assign value to arr_str[i]
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;++i) free(arr_str[i]);
    free(arr_str);
    return 0;
}

void write_to_file(const char *string, const char *fileName)
{//woefully inefficient, but you get the idea
    FILE* outFile = fopen(fileName, "a");
    if (outFile == NULL) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    fprintf(outFile, "%s\n", string);
    fclose(outFile);
}

int alloc_str(char ***str, int offset, int size)
{
    (*str)[offset] = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    if ((*str)[offset] == NULL) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I'm attempting to create an array of strings, but when I run out of memory, I'll just write some of the strings to a file, deallocate the memory they take up, and carry on. I could then refer back to the file to which I wrote the strings I had to clear from memory. In this case, I can ensure, though it does cause some additional overhead, my program will run just fine.
In the second case, freeing memory is a must, though. I *have* to free up the memory required for my program to continue running, but all things considered, it's an easy fixed.

Comment: +1 about "other resources".

Answer (score 1):

It depends. These days operating systems cleanup the mess you made, but on embedded systems you may not be that lucky. But even then there is a question that, "So what, my system busted anyway. I'll just reboot/restart/try again"

Personally I like to arrange my code in a way that when exiting, it checks which resources are in use and free those. It doesn't matter if it's normal exit or error.

Comment: Attemting to freeing resources after a serious error could easily lead to a rain of exceptions from many points, obscuring the original source of the problem.  It's especially problematic with complex, multithreaded apps where the state of the overall process at the time of the error is not known.

Comment: @MartinJames I think asker means errors that can be detected from return values like in the case of `SDL_Init`. Also there's only C tag, so no exceptions.

Comment: Oops..  OK, 'a rain of error messages resulting from 'failed' returns from function calls' :)

Answer (score 0):

Free as much memory as possible and do other necessary work(etc. log, backup) instead of just quit. It is the program's duty to free the memory that it allocated. Do not depend on OS, thought it will free the memory after the program ends.

I wrote a memory leak detect module before long, it require the program free the allocated memory. If it does not free the memory, the module can not work, it can not figure out whether the memory block left is leaked or not.

Comment: This approach is sensibly impossible with complex, multithreaded apps where the state of the process is unknown at the time of the error.  If you are lucky, the logger may still be up for long enough to output something useful before everything blows up.